# can morphia talk to gridfs mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, gridfs

We are planning to use gridfs-mongo to store millions of images. Can we use Morphia to talk to this gridfs database? Also if we use a custom DAO layer (instead of Morphia), how should we handle connection pooling from Java side with Mongo. Please advise.

~vish

Comment: Out of interest: Why do you want to do that (instead of using the file system / S3)? Can you do differential/incremental backups? That's something I'd be interested in if you have GBs and GBs of data in the DB, but I think that's currently not possible in MongoDB.

Comment: Actually the original tiff images will be stored in the filesystem itself. But smaller sized jpg-equivalents of those images(little bigger than thumbnails) will be stored in gridfs. This will help us keep the image and its metadata together and also useful for quick display.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Not sure what kind of traffic you're expecting, but I'd be wary of having the DB as a bottleneck - whereas the filesystem / S3 / CDN might be easier to scale than setting up a MongoDB cluster. Anyway, I think there's some initial support in Morphia, but it's probably not great: http://code.google.com/p/morphia/issues/detail?id=308 Unfortunately, Morphia is currently suffering from a serious lack of progress and hasn't changed much in the last year...

Comment: Thanks Xeraa, we will create a custom dao layer to interact with gridfs. How should we handle connection pooling with Mongodb? Pl advise.

Comment: Quoting Morphia's FAQ (http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions): "Do you have to close connections? Not really. The Mongo driver keeps a connection pool per Mongo instance. If you wish to release those resources, just make sure you stop using the Mongo instance."